# How can I choose which port a web application should use during deployment

Tags: .net, deployment, port

I am using Visual Studio 2010/C#. My goal is to deploy a web application on a windows 2008 R2 server. My main challenge is "how to choose port during the installation".

I have tried the standard deployment project for web projects that are shipped with Visual Studio. However - the choice of deploying the application to use a specific port is not something that I can find easily.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to specify this using the "standard" web deployment installer in VS2010, or do I have to get my hands on something else in order to do this?

(Main reason for this is that other ports are used for other applications on that server, and I would like that the 'deployer' do not have to do anything in the IIS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement a custom action (installation component) in order to change the port - or many other settings in Internet Information Services.

Details of how to do this are available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289522(VS.71).aspx

The example in the link shows how to query the port, shouldn't be too difficult to change it to update the port.